# Newly created users are not saved to the Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

So I am having trouble with my code that creates new users and uploads/stores their user information such as First name, Last name and Email to the firebase database. Whenever I create a user and go onto my firebase databse there is not a new user present.

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error!.localizedDescription)

            return

        }

        let ref = Database.database().reference()

        let usersReference = ref.child("users")

        let uid = user?.user.uid

        let newUserReference = usersReference.child(uid!)

        newUserReference.setValue(["username": self.usernameTextField.text!,"firstname": self.firstnameTextField.text!, "lastname": self.lastnameTextField.text!,"email": self.emailTextField.text!])
```

Comment: Does the user have permission to write to `/users/$uid`? If not, you should see an error message in your debug output, or you can detect errors by adding a completion block: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#add_a_completion_block.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, when new user use your app, they will sign up with email and password, once this is done, you will actually create a profile for him with the code above, right?  If this is the case, probably this is due to your security rule, please paste your security rule here

Comment: Thanks for the recommended solutions. I figured it out... I accidentally wrote Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text! instead of Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally wrote

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!
```

instead of:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

    if error != nil {

        print(error!.localizedDescription)

        return

    } ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@objc func handleSignUp() {
let ref = Database.database().reference
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail:usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        }
        guard let uid = user?.user.uid else {
            return
        }

        // successfully authenticated user
            let values = ["name": "some name", "email": "some email", "username": "your username", "userId": user?.user.uid]
            let userReference = ref.child("user").child(uid)

            let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
            changeRequest?.displayName = self.usernameField.text
            changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: nil)

            userReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                if err != nil {
                    print(err as Any)
                    return
                }
      // add your code here to upload user information to FirebaseDatabase
})
```

Hope that your problem is solved and the solution works for your purposes